# Bundle ID breaks audio in the background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, audio-service

The audio works in the background as long as my `bundle id` is "dev.suragch.flutterAudioServiceDemo" (not mine)

[image]

but if I change `bunde id` to my "com.ambee.new":
[image]
— background stops working.

What's going on? How to make it work with my `bundleId` "com.ambee.new"?

This is my main.dart:

```dart
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart' as audioplayers;
void main() async {
  await setupServiceLocator();
  final _audioHandler = getIt<AudioHandler>();
  _audioHandler.play();
}


GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> setupServiceLocator() async {
  // services
  getIt.registerSingleton<AudioHandler>(await initAudioService());
}

Future<AudioHandler> initAudioService() async {
  return await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
    config: AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.mycompany.myapp.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio Service Demo',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
      androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
    ),
  );
}

class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler {
  final _player = audioplayers.AudioPlayer();

  MyAudioHandler() {
    _player.setReleaseMode(audioplayers.ReleaseMode.LOOP);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() => _player.play(
      'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ambee-cloud.appspot.com/o/Sound%2Fshort.wav?alt=media&token=bd7cc97f-d3d8-490b-9aff-b92df304e145');
}
```

You can reproduce the issue yourself by going to ios -> Runner.xcworkspace from this [repo](https://github.com/tomasbaran/background_test2). Test the background audio loop with a physical iPhone, not simulator.

When you test it with this bundle ID in Xcode:

- **`dev.suragch.flutterAudioServiceDemo`**: once you block the physical iPhone, it keeps looping the audio in background
- **`com.ambee.new`**: once you block the physical iPhone, it STOPS looping the audio in background

Comment: can you try it without "automatically mage signing" and manually adding the bundle id and provisioning profile? clean your app and also delete it on the device plz test it on device.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you need to add the background audio capability to your new bundle ID. Without this being added, the app doesn't have permission to play audio in the background.

You can find the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/enabling_background_audio

Comment: Audio background capability is set up correctly as you can see in the screenshots as well as in the [repo's Info.plist](https://github.com/tomasbaran/background_test2/blob/master/ios/Runner/Info.plist): 
`<key>UIBackgroundModes</key><array><string>audio</string></array>`

Comment: Adding bounty to this answer since it was the only submission, not because it necessarily answered the question.